# Symfony2 Doctrine entity not hydrated

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

I get an entity `Member` from the entity manager, did a var_dump, everything ok except for the manyToOne relation with `Family`, so I tried a `var_dump($member->getFamily());` and surprisingly, the only correct value was the family's ID, all the other properties were null (which is not the case in the database...)

Here is my Member stuff

```
/**
 * @var Family
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Family", inversedBy="members")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="family_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $family;
```

And my Family entity stuff

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Member", mappedBy="family", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $members;
```

All getters and setters are generated by Doctrine. It's just that only the id seems to be hydrated, not the rest. Any idea ?

**EDIT : the var_dump result**

```
private 'family' => 
object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Family)[427]
  public '__initializer__' => 
    object(Closure)[405]
  public '__cloner__' => 
    object(Closure)[406]
  public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
  private 'id' (AppBundle\Entity\Family) => int 1
  private 'members' (AppBundle\Entity\Family) => null
  private 'adress' (AppBundle\Entity\Family) => null
  protected 'telephone' => null
  protected 'email' => null
  private 'nom' (AppBundle\Entity\Family) => null
  private 'isValid' (AppBundle\Entity\Family) => null
```

Comment: Are you initializing the `$members` property to an `ArrayCollection` instance in the `Family` constructor?

Comment: Doctrine lazy-loads data by default, did you join the family in your query? Do a family->getWhatever() call and see if the entity gets loaded.

Comment: Im trying to get the value through a simple `$family = $em->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Member)->find($id)->getFamily();` and yes it's initialized to an ArrayCollection

Comment: @solarBanana I think this behavior is ok, look at [these](http://www.slideshare.net/Ocramius/proxy-ooppatterninphp) slides. Doctrine uses Proxy pattern (also ghost objects)..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctrine lazy-loads data unless you join it in your query (and add its alias to the select() call). This means you get a proxy like in your example, not a real `Family` entity. The proxy only has the one field it has access to, the family_id.

Until you call a non-`getId` function on the object (like `getNom()`) this stays a proxy, but at that call doctrine does the query to load it completely. This will happen even if you pass that family proxy to twig.

Comment: thanks for that ! But now, if I want to return it as a Json Response, (through JSM_Serializer), will there be any problems ?