# How can I output ManyToOne data with doctrine (Symfony 4)?

Tags: arrays, symfony, oop, doctrine, entity

This is my entity "data":

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DataRepository")
*/
class Data
{
  /**
  * @ORM\Id()
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  */
  private $id;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, unique=true)
  */
  private $uuid;



  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
  */
  private $content;



  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Fields")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="field", referencedColumnName="id")
   */

  private $fields;



  public function getId(): ?int
  {
    return $this->id;
  }



  public function getContent()
  {
    return $this->content;
  }

  public function setContent($content)
  {
    $this->content = $content;
  }




  public function getUuid(): ?string
  {
    return $this->uuid;
  }

  public function setUuid(string $uuid): self
  {
    $this->uuid = $uuid;

    return $this;
  }


  public function getFields(): ?Fields
  {
    return $this->fields;
  }

  public function setFields(?Fields $fields): self
  {
    $this->fields = $fields;

    return $this;
  }


}
```

I am getting the data via doctrine:

```
$output = $this->em->getRepository(Data::class)->findAll();
```

The output:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Data {#7060 ▼
    -id: 1
    -uuid: "12345"
    -content: "blabla"
    -fields: Fields {#7164 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 6
      -name: null
      -uuid: null
      -productgroup: null
      -type: null
       …2
    }
  }
  1 => Data {#7165 ▶}
]
```

The problem is, that the data of the ManyToOne "fields" captures only the id. But not the name or productgroup. It is all "null". But in my database it is not null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Doctrine entity not hydrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355584/symfony2-doctrine-entity-not-hydrated)

Comment: @Fabian Ah ok! This was confusing me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happen when you are dumping objects with relations. For checking that fields relation has not null values. Do this:

```
dump($output[0]->getFields()->getName())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because relations from doctrine are not loaded in this case.

If you access the relation before, e.g.

```
$output->fields
```

The relation will actually be loaded and the fields won't be null if you dump it afterwards

See [Relationships and Proxy Classes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#fetching-related-objects)

Answer (score 1):

This is cause by doctrine lazy loading, in order to avoid overloading memmory.
As @AythaNzt says, if you loop trougth entities you will be able to acces their properties (when you as for getField() doctrine trigger a query to fetch their data)

Check this to display all child fields: [Avoid lazy loading Doctrine Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763867/avoid-lazy-loading-doctrine-symfony2)

Comment: I tested `* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Fields" fetch="EAGER")` but I get an error message

Comment: [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'fetch' at position 37 in property App\Entity\Data::$fields.